# Clipping changes are not affecting in the input in vtk

Tags: visual-studio, vtk

I am developing a sample application in which iam using **vtkplanes** to crop the **surfaceRendered** output.

The changes are visualizing on the **vtkRenderWindow** clearly without any problem,but when i convert it into **stl** file the cropped changes are not saved instead it is saving the 3D object  before i made the cropping.

here is my code

```
mapper->SetInputConnection( surfaceRenderedOutput->GetOutputPort() );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane6 );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane1 );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane2 );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane3 );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane5 );
mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane4 );
mapper->Update();


surfaceRenderedOutput->SetInputConnection(mapperr->GetOutputPort());
surfaceRenderedOutput->Update();
```

To write to stl i  used like this

```
          stlWriter->SetInput(surfaceRenderedOutput->GetOutput());
            stlWriter->Write();
```

Can anyone help please

**EDIT**

I did like this

```
       //vtkClipPolyData//
     clipper1->SetClipFunction(plane1);
      clipper2->SetClipFunction(plane2);
       clipper3->SetClipFunction(plane3);
        clipper4->SetClipFunction(plane4);
        clipper5->SetClipFunction(plane5);
        clipper6->SetClipFunction(plane6);

            polyd1=clipper1->GetOutput();
            polyd2=clipper2->GetOutput();
            polyd3=clipper3->GetOutput();
            polyd4=clipper4->GetOutput();
            polyd5=clipper5->GetOutput();
            polyd6=clipper6->GetOutput();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData> appendFilter = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData>::New();
        appendFilter->SetNumberOfInputs(6);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd1);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd2);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd3);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd4);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd5);
        appendFilter->AddInput(polyd6);
        appendFilter->Update();


       stlWriter->SetInput(appendFilter->GetOutput());
```

still im not getting the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapper doesn't do anything to the surfaceRenderedOutput.  The output of the mapper presumably goes to a vtkActor which then goes to the vtkRenderWindow.

You want the output of the mapper.  What is its type?

For the vtkClipPolyData object there is a getClippedOutput method which should allow you to get a clipped mesh.

Comment: mapper is of type vtkPolyDataMapper

Comment: in vtkclipPolyData how should i add multiple planes in `SetClipFunction`

Comment: vtkClipPolyData can take a variety of types of implicit functions.  For multiple clipping planes you can use the **vtkPlanes** function, which is a set of multiple vtkPlanes.  Here's the doc:  https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPlanes.html

Comment: i have used this      `vtkClipConvexPolyData ` and        iam getting the clipped part but it is taking sooo much time.

Comment: Yeah, that’s because the clipping is done in analytically software. The clipping planes in the renderer don’t actually clip the polygons. They just tell the GPU which pixels can ignore the polygons.

Comment: thank you for your information sir :)..  Is there any other way?

Comment: help please sir

Comment: Is this in an interactive application?  My only thought is that you use the RenderWindow clipping planes while the user is interacting. Then when they've stopped or finished, use vtkClipConvexPolyData to compute the actual result.  If that's not sufficient, you'll have to reduce the number of polygons or get a faster computer.

Comment: can you explain why vtkAppendPolyData does not give the result?doesnt it adds all polydatas?

Comment: can you answer this 
   https://stackoverflow.com/q/61817497/12008298

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I would suggestion asking over at the VTK discourse, discourse.vtk.org.  That's where the VTK developers and users hang out.